# How much session data is too much?

Tags: java, session, memory-management

We are running into unusually high memory usage issues. And I observed that many places in our code we are pulling 100s of records from DB, packing it in custom data objects, adding it to an arraylist and storing in session. I wish to know what is the recommended upper limit storing data in session. Just a good practice bad practice kind of thing.

I am using JRockit 1.5 and 1.6GB of RAM. I did profiling with Jprobe and found that some parts of app have very heavy memory footprint. Most of this data is being into session to be used later.

Comment: I am running a J2EE struts app on Weblogic 10

Comment: It's a platform agnostic question really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends entirely on how many sessions are typically present (which in turn depends on how many users you have, how long they stay on the site, and the session timeout) and how much RAM your server has.

But first of all: have you actually used a memory profiler to tell you that your "high memory usage" is caused by session data, or are you just guessing?

If the only problem you have is "high memory usage" on a production machine (i.e. it can handle the production load but is not performing as well as you'd like), the easiest solution is to get more RAM for the server - much quicker and cheaper than redesigning the app.

But caching entire result sets in the session is bad for a different reason as well: what if the data changes in the DB and the user expects to see that change? If you're going to cache, use [one of the existing systems](http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions) that do this at the DB request level - they'll allow you to cache results between users and they have facilities for cache invalidation.

Comment: Added some more details in the question.

Answer (score 6):

If you're storing data in session to improve performance, consider using true caching since cache is application-wide, whereas session is per-user, which results in unneccessary duplication of otherwise similar objects.

If, however, you're storing them for user to edit this objects (which I doubt, since hundreds of objects is way too much), try minimizing the amount of data stored or research optimistic concurrency control.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this heavily depends on the number of active sessions you expect. If you're writing an intranet application with < 20 users, it's certainly no problem to put a few MB in the session. However, if you're expecting 5000 live session for instance, each MB of data stored per session accounts for 5GB of RAM.

However, I'd generally recommend not to store any data from DB in session. Just fetch from DB for every request. If performance is an issue, use an application-wide cache (e.g. Hibernate's 2nd level cache).

Answer (score 1):

What *kind* of data is it? Is it really needed per session or could it be cached at application level? Do you really need all the columns or only a subset? How often is it being accessed? What pages does it need to be available on? And so on.

It may make much more sense to retrieve the records from the DB when you really need to. Storing hundreds of records in session is never a good strategy.

Comment: Its needed per session, I cannot cache it app level. Won't it be performance toll if I retrieve every-time from DB even when I gain some on memory

Comment: And you need *all* the column data? And all those rows? On every page? You must be able to optimize that a bit. And yeah, generally storing hundreds of full-blown records in Session, regardless of load etc., is not a good strategy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say try to store the minimum amount of data that will be enough to recreate the necessary environment in a subsequent request. If you're storing in memory to avoid a database round-trip, then a true caching solution such as Memcache might be helpful.

If you're storing these sessions in memory instead of a database, then the round-trip is saved, and requests will be served faster as long as the memory load is low, and there's no paging. Once the number of clients goes up and paging begins, most clients will see a huge degradation in response times. Both these variables and inversely related.

Its better to measure the latency to your database server, which is usually low enough in most cases to be considered as a viable means of storage instead of in-memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try to split the data you are currently storing in the session into user-specific and static data. Then implement caching for all the static parts. This will give you a lot of reuse application-wide and still allow you to cache the specific data a user is working on.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make per-user mini sqlite database and connect to it, and store the data the user is accessing in it, then just retrieve the records from it, while the user is requesting it, and after the user disconnects just delete the sqlite database.